# Deprecation of isblank("string") in Julia 0.4

Tags: julia

I'm doing text parsing in Julia and need to test if certain strings are blank (in order to parse into floats). I have been using `isblank()` booleans in <0.4 Julia, but after upgrading to 0.4, I get the following warning:

```
julia> isblank(q)
WARNING: isblank(s::AbstractString) is deprecated, use all((c->begin 
            c == ' ' || c == '\t'
        end),s) instead.
 in depwarn at deprecated.jl:73
 in isblank at deprecated.jl:50
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
true
```

What replaced `isblank()`? Is the above really the replacement? My googling didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the replacement.

Basically in [#5939](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5939) and related issues, it was revealed that answering `isblank` is a lot harder than it might first appear given Unicode complexities.
The deprecation occurred in [#8233](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/8233).

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks natural, it must be a replacement in new version, you can add the line bellow in your code and replace (using Ctrl+H) all `isblank(` with `isblk(`. I wish it works for you.

```
isblk(s)=all((c->begin c == ' ' || c == '\t' end),s)
```

now `isblk([]) # => true`

Comment: Thanks, but I think a better approach is to implement a try/catch block here.